# To prove $\| g\|_p\leq \int_X \|f^y\|_p \ d\mu (y).$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

> > Let $(X,S, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $1<p<\infty$. Let $f:X\times X \to \mathbb R$ be such that, for every $y\in X$, the section $f^y$ is $p$-integrable and that $$\displaystyle \int_X \|f^y\|_p \  d\mu(y) <+\infty.$$ Define, for $x\in X$, $$g(x)=\displaystyle \int_X f(x,y) d\mu(y).$$ Show that $g\in L^p(\mu)$ and that $$\|g\|_p\leq \displaystyle \int_X \|f^y\|_p \ d\mu(y).$$

So above is the problem. We need to show (after simplifying the inequality) that $$\left(\displaystyle \int_X \left | \int_X f(x,y) \ d\mu(y)\right |^p d \mu (x)\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq  \displaystyle \int_X \left ( \int_X \left | f(x,y)\right |^p \ d\mu (x)\right )^\frac{1}{p} \ d\mu(y).$$

Can you please give me some hints on how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: **Hint:** Jensen inequality.

Comment: Can you explain how you simplified the inequality? It looks like all you’ve done is just write out the inequality without simplifying at all.

Comment: I think this does not depend on the norm you choose: Pick any norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $X$, then you want to prove $$\left\|\int_X f(\cdot,y)\,\mathrm dy\right\|\le \int_X\| f(\cdot, y)\|\,\mathrm dy,$$ for all sufficiently regular $f$, which is just a continuous analogue of the triangle inequality and maybe you can prove this using the construction of the integral from simple functions (even though the technicalities may be annoying). Jensen applied in the norm-sense should work at least if $\mu(X)=1$ (the norm is convex), but not directly to $x\mapsto x^{1/p}$ (which is concave for $p,x>0$.)

Answer (score 0):

When $X$ is $\sigma$-finite, this is just the Minkowski integral inequality with $Y = X$, which you can prove using the "duality" representation of the $p$-norm: If $(E, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite, then for *any* measurable $f : E \to [0, \infty]$, $p \in [1, \infty]$,
$$\lVert f \rVert_{L^p} = \sup\{\int_{E}fg\,d\mu : g \geq 0, \lVert g \rVert_{L^q} = 1\}.$$

The above identity for $\lVert f \rVert_{L^p}$ also holds when $(E, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ is not $\sigma$-finite, provided $\lVert f \rVert_{L^p} < \infty$.

To prove Minkowski's integral inequality, you can use the above identity and upper bound the integrals appearing in the supremum.